# obtener el valor de una fila completa con revolution/laravel-google-sheets con Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-api

estoy trabajando con php 8 laravel 8.8 y revolution/laravel-google-sheets, leo perfectamente toda la hoja de calculo, lo que necesito es cuando un usuario se loguee, busque en esa hoja la fila cuyo identificador es la columna A (Legajo) y poder obtener datos relacionado a ese empleado, mi codigo hasta el momento es el siguiente:

```
public function index(){
     $legajo = auth()->user()->legajo;  
     $employees = Sheets::spreadsheet(config('google.post_spreadsheet_id'))->sheet('Personal')->range('A:AL')->get(); 
   $header = [
         "Legajo", "Apellido", "Nombres","Estado","DNI","Cuil", "Fecha de Nacimiento",
         "Edad","Nacionalidad","Estudios Completados","Titulo","Estado Civil", "Hijos",
         "Hijos con certificado CDU", "Grupo Sanguineo","Telefono Fijo",
         "Telefono Celular", "Telefono de Contacto",
         "Nombre de Contacto","e-Mail","Direccion de D.N.I.","Calle", "Numero","Piso", "Depto.",
         "Torre", "Bloque","Barrio","Ciudad","Provincia","CBU","Banco", "Fecha de Ingreso",
         "Antigüedad","Poliza ART","Seguro de Vida","Categoria", "Puesto / Funcion",
      ];
  
  $employeesList= Sheets::collection($header, $employees);
  $buscar = array_search($employeesList, $employees[0][$legajo]);
  $estado= $employeesList['Estado'][$buscar];
  $puesto= $employeesList['Puesto / Funcion'][$buscar];
    if($estado=='Activo'{
       return view('autogestion.inicio');  
    }else{
      return view('autogestion.inicio_baja');  
    }
}
```

Me arroja siguiente error:

ErrorException
Undefined array key 1807 (1807) es el numero legajo del usuario que se logueo

el dd($employeesList) me muestra (imagen del primer registro):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

luego de analizar el problema, decidí crear una tarea que se ejecute cada cierto tiempo y inserte esos datos en una tabla y se terminó el problema.